# How to prevent specific buffers from opening when starting Emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Everytime I start emacs, I have a series of orgmode buffers open (even though I close them before exiting). Do you know how to set emacs so that it opens only with my current setup (currently it shoudl only open shoring my agenda and a todo orgmode buffer on the left, but, while it does this, it also shows other opened buffers in the background (!). Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: When you open the agenda, then all the files that contribute to it are opened. If you don't want them opened at startup, then don't open the agenda at startup.

Comment: I guess that's it. So as long as the agenda is open, those buffers will be always open?

Comment: Yes, unless you close them by hand. But when you reopen the agenda, they will be reopened as well. And IIRC in some cases, Org mode *assumes* that they are always open, so if you close them, you *might* get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs out of the box does not open anything by itself at startup. You are probably using some package (internal or external) that offers this feature. Maybe desktop-save-mode?
For example, I use workgroups2. It opens at startup, everything that was open at exit. But that means - everything I close before the exit will not be opened on startup. I can highly recommend workgroups2.